# Using method with quartz in Dependency injection blows up memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, entity-framework-core, quartz.net

I use Quartz calling a method which uses EF Core. If I call that specific method every second via WebAPI there is no issue but if I call that method via Quartz every second my memory (heap) blows up within seconds.

Note this is just a demo project to simplify my original issue.
Here is my dependency injection configuration in my `Program.cs`:

```cs
builder.Services
    .AddSingleton<JobManager>()
    .AddTransient<Job>()
    .AddTransient<IMemoryLeakingService, MemoryLeakingService>()
    .AddTransient<IDbConnectionStringHelper, DbConnectionStringHelper>()
    .AddTransient<IJobFactory, JobFactory>()
    .AddTransient<ISchedulerFactory, StdSchedulerFactory>()
    .AddDbContext<IMyContext, MyContext>((provider, options) =>
    {
        options.UseSqlite(provider.GetRequiredService<IDbConnectionStringHelper>().ConnectionString);
        options.EnableSensitiveDataLogging();
        options.EnableDetailedErrors();
    }, ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient)
    ;
```

I use that `JobManager` to start the job:

```cs
public class JobManager
{
    private readonly ILogger<JobManager> _logger;
    private readonly IJobFactory _jobFactory;
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;

    private IScheduler _scheduler;


    public JobManager(ILogger<JobManager> logger, IJobFactory jobFactory, ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _jobFactory = jobFactory;
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }

    public async Task StartJobs()
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("{Method}()", nameof(StartJobs));
        _scheduler = _schedulerFactory.GetScheduler().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _scheduler.JobFactory = _jobFactory;


        var everySecondTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.RepeatSecondlyForever(1)).Build();

        var job = JobBuilder.Create<Job>().Build();

        var triggersAndJobs = new Dictionary<IJobDetail, IReadOnlyCollection<ITrigger>>
        {
            {job, new HashSet<ITrigger> {everySecondTrigger}},
        };

        await _scheduler.ScheduleJobs(triggersAndJobs, false).ConfigureAwait(false);

        await _scheduler.Start().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

Here is the Code of my `Job`:

```cs
public class Job : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<Job> _logger;
    private readonly IMemoryLeakingService _memoryLeakingService;

    public Job(ILogger<Job> logger, IMemoryLeakingService memoryLeakingService)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _memoryLeakingService = memoryLeakingService;
    }
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("{method}({context})", nameof(Execute), context);
        await _memoryLeakingService.ReadData();
    }
}
```

With the `MemoryLeakingService` and `ReadData()` which is called by the job:

```cs
public class MemoryLeakingService : IMemoryLeakingService
{
    private readonly ILogger<MemoryLeakingService> _logger;
    private readonly IMyContext _context;
    private readonly List<string> _strings;

    public MemoryLeakingService(ILogger<MemoryLeakingService> logger, IMyContext context)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _context = context;
        _strings = new List<string>();
        var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            _strings.Add(guid);
        }
    }
    
    public async Task ReadData()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("{method}() called", nameof(WriteData));
        var demoEntities = await _context.DemoEntities.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

[image: VS Diagnostics]

The first 255 seconds I did call `ReadData()` via a WebAPI request, heap is not blowing up, but as I start my QuartzJob, the number of referenced objects increases dramatically within seconds. Why is there a difference between calling the method via WebRequest and calling that same method via Quartz?
The objects using the memory are the Changed Tracked Objects by EF Core. But I have no idea why this is different when using Quartz.

If you are interested, you can clone the whole demo project from [my Github repo](https://github.com/pkuehnel/QuartzMemoryLeak).

Comment: Click "View heap" to see the objects taking up memory?

Comment: That's not my problem, I know the instances in the ChangeTracker of EfCore are taking the memory. I just don't know why my Contexts don't get disposed. I updated the question and added an answer but I still don't know why my solution above is not working.

Comment: I think your MemoryLeakingService should implement IDisposable?

Answer (score 0):

I updated my `Job` to not directly get the service via dependency injection but consume an `IServiceScopeFactory` and create a scope for my service. This resolves my memory leak, but I am not quite sure why directly consuming the service leads to a memory leak. I also found out that this issue only occurs if I use a EFCore context but not if I blow up my service with a list of strings.

Here the new code:

```cs
public class Job : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<Job> _logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;

    public Job(ILogger<Job> logger, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
    }
    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogTrace("{method}({context})", nameof(Execute), context);
        using var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
        var memoryLeakingService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMemoryLeakingService>();
        await memoryLeakingService.ReadData();
    }
}
```